# Zeroes of multivariate polynomials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials

Assume you have $m$ points $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and you want to find a polynomial $p$ in $d$ indeterminates such that $p(x_i)=0$ for all $i$, and the value of $p(x)$ is negative at any other point. Is this possible/can you construct one such polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Let $p$ be

$$p(x) = -\prod_{i=1}^m ||x-x_i||^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Note that the Euclidean distance from a point $x\in \Bbb R^d$ to the point $x_1$ is always positive, except that it is $0$ at $x_1$. In addition, if you *square* the distance, what you have is a polynomial.

And the same is true for all the other points $x_i$. So if you multiply them all together you get a polynomial which is $0$ only at the points $x_i$, and strictly positive everywhere else. Finally, if you put a minus sign in front, you get the polynomial you're after.